# Django: Is there a way to apply an aggregate function on a window function?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have already made a raw SQL of this query as a last resort.

I have a gaps-and-islands problem, where I get the respective groups with two `ROW_NUMBER` -s. Later on I use a `COUNT` and a `MAX` like so:

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(count)
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT players.id, players.name,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY match_details.id, goals.time) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY match_details.id, players.id ORDER BY match_details.id, goals.time)) AS grp
        FROM match_details
        JOIN players
        ON players.id = match_details.player_id
        JOIN goals
        ON goals.match_detail_id = match_details.id
        ORDER BY match_details.id, goals.time
    ) AS x
    GROUP BY grp, id, name
    ORDER BY count DESC
) AS y
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY MAX(count) DESC, name
```

players example:

```
id  | name
----+-------
1   | John
2   | Mark
```

match_details example:

```
id  | player_id    
----+------------
1   | 1          
2   | 1          
3   | 2          
4   | 2
```

goals example:

```
id  | match_detail_id  | time    
----+------------------+---------
1   | 1                | 2
2   | 1                | 10
3   | 2                | 2
4   | 3                | 1
5   | 3                | 5
6   | 4                | 6
```

output example:

```
id  | name   | max
----+--------+---------
1   | John   | 2
2   | Mark   | 2
```

So far, I have finished the innermost query with Django ORM, but when I try to annotate over `group` , it throws an error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls
```

I haven't yet wrapped my head around using `Subquery`, but I'm also not sure if that would work at all. I do *not* need to filter over the window function, only use aggregates on it.

Is there a way to solve this with plain Django, or do I have to resort to hybrid raw-ORM queries, perhaps to `django-cte` ?

Comment: the query is unreadable, you can remove the columns that you don't need, also read please https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Post  your actual query or at least a representative example, your table definition (ddl) sample data as text - **no images**- or better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14). Also, post the expected results of that data. You would benefit from spending a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/) and reviewing [ask].

Comment: Edited the question, thank you for your comments. I thought there is no need since its a question about the possibility of nesting this with ORM, but now at least I know to include clear examples/sample data for everything